# Xamarin Forms : Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin forms app for learning and everything is working for iOS etc, Android was working and now, for a reason I cant work out.  Something is wrong with the AppSupport.

Min SDK 15, Target 21.  I have references to v4,v7 AppCompat, GooglePlayServices, Maps

values.xml(0,0): Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'. (APT0000)

values.xml(0,0): Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'. (APT0000)

I have done a clean, rebuild etc

**Update**

I think its Xamarin that is broken :(
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29568

Comment: Which versions are you running?

Comment: Xamarin Studio on a mac, or which version of Android?

Comment: Try with everything.

Comment: I am running 22.2.0 I think, bloody thing is well confused

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had corrupt packages in ./local/shared/Xamarin

Comment: ... and how did you resolve these corrupt packages? did you simply delete the contents of that folder?

Comment: Yes I cleared out all the packages so it re-downloaded them all

Comment: For windows try this path
%localappdata%\Xamarin

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had no package in ./local/shared/Xamarin on mac. There was only 1 hidden file: ".machineid".

Comment: Did you fix it though?

Comment: Similar problem here on Visual Studio for Mac template application.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this when I copied in one XF android project into another.  Turns out the styles.xml was looking for assets that hadn't been copied over yet. Make sure you've copied your styles and visual assets such as icons over.