# No resource found that matches the given name (at > 'drawable' with value > '@drawable/design_ic_visibility' Xamarin.froms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I am working in xamarin.forms. Suddenly My project stops working. PCL is built successful but xamarin.android project gives me an error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'drawable' with value
>   '@drawable/design_ic_visibility').    ERecall.Android D:\ERecall\ERecall_Code\ERecall\ERecall.Android\obj\Debug__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\library_project_imports\res\drawable-v21\design_password_eye.xml  16

This kind of total 219 errors.

Version :

```
Xamarin.forms : 2.3.4.267
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.v7.AppCompat : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.v7.MediaRouter : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.v7.RecyclerView : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.vector.Drawable : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.Annotations : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.compat : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.Core.UI : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.Core.Utils : 25.4.0.2
Xamarin.Andorid.Support.Media.compat : 25.4.0.2
```

Comment: do you have "design_ic_visibility"? what is build action on it?

Comment: I don't have any thing with this name. D:\ERecall\ERecall\ERecall\ERecall.Android\obj\Debug\resourcecache\0170AD1733F6E19420992C1114D6E409\res\drawable\mr_ic_play_light.xml(20): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_play_light'). This kind of output.

Comment: this is different error than in original question. Do you get many of them? Try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: I tried 100 times but every time same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934970/xamarin-forms-error-apt0000-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-fou?rq=1

Comment: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Xamarin There are some set of packages in this path but I think it's corrupted.

Comment: I suggest to do updates using SDK manager and repair xamarin installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153076/discussion-between-rutul-mehta-and-yuri-s).